# Weird position absolute chrome bug

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-position

I'm absolutely positioning elements inside floating divs. The last absolutely positioned elements sticks to the top of the div in chrome until we resize the window (see [here](http://siscode.me/c/1_1-2-3-4-5-6_38-201-_1-210-_5-245-))

Things I tried so far:

- Putting a container inside the floating element
- Overflow: hidden/auto to the floats, elements and container

This only happens in chrome. Any idea why/what is happening?

[image]

Comment: Chrome and OS version?

Comment: Chrome Version 26.0.1410.43, OS: Ubuntu 12.04, 12.10 and Mac OS X 10.8.3

Comment: Cant see which element you are talking about. Using Chrome 26 on Win7. Can you describe (print screen) the element in question...

Comment: Any chance you can provide an unminified version of your javascript? I've had a similar issue in the past with webkit where the position of an element was off, but all the rules of css positioning were being followed correctly. I 'fixed' it that time by forcing a redraw when the element needed to be shown, but i would be interested in trying to find a proper solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only small thing you have to do and everything else is great. Use this

```
.schedule-course-slot-wrapper {
position: absolute; /*Important*/
border: thin solid;
border-radius: 3px;
margin: 0 2px;
padding: 0 3px;
height: 100%;
}
```

instead

```
.schedule-course-slot-wrapper {
position: relative; /*Important*/
border: thin solid;
border-radius: 3px;
margin: 0 2px;
padding: 0 3px;
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks man. Do you have an idea why it was behaving this way?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
pop.style.left = l+"px";
pop.style.top = t+"px";
```

instead of

```
pop.style.posLeft = l;
pop.style.posTop = t;
```

or both.